# Using Spring Pitchfork to have Java EE compliant code that runs in non-Java EE container

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, containers

I am facing the decision to abandon Java EE 5 container to use web container instead (with Spring). According to Interface21 Spring Pitchfork allows elements of the Java EE programming model to be used in Spring. Thus, I get a subset of Java EE annotations inside of Spring container. Since I prefer to maintain compatibility with Java EE this looks as attractive option to me. What is your experience with Pitchfork and what did you accomplish by using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No experience with Pitchfork, but lots with Spring.  Foregoing EJBs hasn't been a problem.  POJOs have been more than adequate.

Two other alternatives to consider:

You can use OpenEJB with Tomcat if you need EJBs, want to stick with Tomcat, and don't want to switch to a purchased or open source Java EE app server.

You can try Spring dm Server with OSGi.  Eat the shell and the egg - go all the way.

Comment: We ended up with OpenEJB running on Tomcat. Due to large J2EE legacy code base switching to Spring seemed less feasible. But using POJOs and JPA makes things very similar with Spring anyway. OpenEJB infrastructure is more than adequate - with Spring we would have to use more 3d party products.

Comment: I'm glad this worked out for you, grigory.  Sounds like some good work on your part.

Comment: *but don't want to **buy** a Java EE app server* - do note that this sounds like a Java EE server must always be bought. In reality the most frequently used Java EE application server is JBoss AS which is free as in free beer and completely open source. So are Glassfish, Geronimo and a bunch of others.

Comment: I realize that there are plenty of open source implementations of EJB 3.1.  The purchase I'm referring to in either case is the commitment to the EJB platform.  I'll amend my wording to reflect your very good point.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. It's probably the difference between "buy a" and "buy into" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use pitchfork for unit testing EJB3 and JPA components outside of the container and it works really well.  I can wire up everything I need including a transaction manager, a 2nd level caching provider, etc.

Comment: As an alternative to using something like pitchfork, you might want to consider Arquillian (http://www.jboss.org/arquillian). Java EE 6 also gained the ability to run the EJB container in embedded mode in, which makes unit testing much easier.